# Next.js use HTTPS over HTTP

Tags: ssl, heroku, next.js, namecheap

I deployed my Nextjs app to Heroku and I created a domain in Namecheap pointing to it.

In my Heroku settings I have SSL enabled, so, https connection is allowed.

My question now is: how can force user to use https over http ? I mean, everytime I visit my website [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) (or mywebsite.com) I got redirected to http://www.mywebsite.com but I should be redirected to https://www.mywebsite.com instead.

Any idea ?